# Python: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

I am trying to get the md5 checksum of some files and write them into a temp file.

```
import os
import hashlib

PID = str(os.getpid()) 
manifest = open('/temp/tmp/MANIFEST.'+ PID + '.tmp','w') #e.g. MANIFEST.48938.tmp
for elmt in files_input:
    input = open(elmt['file'], "r", 'us-ascii') #'us-ascii' when I ran "file --mime"
    manifest.write(hashlib.md5(input.read()).hexdigest())
```

From this I get a Python error that I haven't able to resolve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "etpatch.py", line 131, in <module>
    input = open(elmt['file'], "r", 'us-ascii')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Some people have had this error from doing "from os import *" but I am not doing this nor am I using import * on any other module.

Comment: Where did you get the idea for the `us-ascii` argument from? That third argument is supposed to give a buffer size (or 0 for unbuffered, or 1 for line buffered)

Comment: on a *nix shell: file --mime-encoding <filename>

Comment: No, I mean why did you give that as the third argument to open?

Comment: Took it out. See my comment under NPE's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is expected to be an integer:

> ```
> open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
> ```
>
> The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes). A negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If omitted, the system default is used. [2]

Comment: Thanks. If I take out the offending argument, I get "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" in the next line I use hashlib. I tried doing "open(elmt['file'], "r", encoding='us-ascii')" but I get the same error.